# Generate random number & after adding/subtract them comparing the result in objective c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, random

As I'm from other scripting language background, I'm not so much expert in objective-c & iPhone programming. 
I've tried some code of objective-c myself, but they aren't working as I expected.

I have elaborated my requirements on this image: [image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81691511/Math.jpg]

So I'm seeking a help from the experts about my program-

1. I want to make a program for iPhone in objective-C that will generate random number & generate signs (like +, -, *, /).
2. Then it will subtract/add/multiply/divide with random values in 2 different sections.
3. Now users have to compare between two sections.
4. Is the result of 2 sections are = or < or > . There will be three individual buttons for the signs.
5. After getting the press on the button from the user a new label will show the answer, if it is right/wrong.
6. If the answer is wrong, it will show the correct answer also.

Any help on this program on objective-c language required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code, that you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

To generate a random number in a range use:

```
int randomInteger = arc4random_uniform(range);
```

To generate a random operator character:

```
NSArray  *operators = @[@"+", @"-", @"*", @"/"];
int       randomOperatorIndex = arc4random_uniform(4);
NSString *randomOperator = operators[randomOperatorIndex];
```

The rest of the code you need to figure out and write yourself. If you have problems post another question with the problem code for help with it.

Notes:
`arc4random()` is a high quality 32-bit pseudo-random number generator that does not need to be seeded, it seeds itself on a regular basis from the kernel strong random number subsystem.

`arc4random_uniform(range)` returns an integer in the range of 0 to (range-1). It has the added benefit that it avoids "modulo bias" that the mod (%) operator does.

Comment: I have 2 labels. I want to generate random operators(4) on both of them. Any suggestions on how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `arc4random()` to generate random no.

Use following to generate random operator

```
-(NSString*) getRamdomOperator
{
    int randNum = arc4random_uniform(4);

    NSString *operator;

    switch(randNum)
    {
        case 0:
        operator = @"+";
        break;

        case 1:
        operator = @"-";
        break;

        case 2:
        operator = @"/";
        break;

        case 3:
        operator = @"*";
        break;

        Default:
        break;
     }

   return operator;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `rand()`, it is not very random and needs a good seed. Instead use `arc4random()` and in this case of a limited range `arc4random_uniform()`. Example for this case: `int randNum = arc4random_uniform(4);`, this eliminates any minor bias and is simpler as tell.

Comment: Method names should not start with "get", that is reserved for methods that return results with a reference argument. A better name would be simply: "ramdomOperator". See Apple's [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001751-BCIJHEDH)

Comment: @wuiii - When I generate both numbers & operators , I want to calculate them on pressing the button.
 - As displayed on the actual post image: res1 & res2 have different numbers & operators. They need to be calculate differently also.

any suggestion ?